# Auto-mounting network shares per user

Tags: 11.04, mount, sharing, cifs

I have a server that has a number of CIFS shares that need to be accessed on a per-user basis. For example, I have a *Music* share which I have full access to, but my wife has read-only access.

When either myself or my wife log into our Ubuntu 11.04 laptop I would like these shares to be automatically mounted per user. Now I understand that if I mount as `-t cifs` without specifying a user then it will use the `USER` environment variable. However, I also need to specify a password, so how can I do that when each user has a different password?

I think my questions are:

1. Is there a way for me to have a per-user */etc/fstab*?
2. If not, is there a way to specify that a mount is only applicable to a certain user?
3. Also, the share password is always the same as the local password. Is there a way to specify that this password should just pass through from the client to server rather than having to specify it in a credentials file somewhere?

Or maybe I'm missing something and there's a completely different solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably several solutions possible; here's is how I would do it.
*(Disclaimer: untested!)*

The [mount.cifs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/mount.cifs.8.html)
command can read the username and password from the `USER` and
`PASSWD` environmental variables, but it can also read them from a
"credentials" file, that you specify on the command line with the `-o
cred=/path/to/credentials/file` option.

The credentials-file approach is IMHO simpler to implement.

1. Create a text file `$HOME/.Music.cred` to store the credentials;
   the file should have this format:

   ```
   user=your-username-on-cifs-server
   password=the-password
   domain=leave-this-blank-unless-really-using-windows-domains
   ```
2. Protect the `$HOME/.Music.cred` file; run this command in a terminal:

   ```
   chmod go-rw $HOME/.Music.cred
   ```
3. Now you should be able to mount the CIFS share `//server/music` on
   directory `MyMusicFolder` using this command:

   ```
   sudo mount -t cifs -o cred=$HOME/.Music.cred //server/music $HOME/MyMusicFolder
   ```

   You can enable each user to run this through passwordless [sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudo) by
   adding a line to `/etc/sudoers`: (one line per user)

   ```
   # replace every occurence of `user` with the actual account name
   user ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/mount -t cifs -o cred=/home/user/.Music.cred //server/music /home/user/MyMusicFolder
   ```
4. If the command from step 3. worked correctly, you can make it
   automatic in several ways:

   - save it into a shell script into your home directory and make
     that script an auto-started application (you have to do this for
     every user that needs to mount CIFS shares);
   - save it into a shell script `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/30mount-cifs-shares` 
     so that it will work for any user.

Alternatively, you can replace steps 3. and 4. above with the use of
[pam-mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man5/pam_mount.conf.5.html):

1. install package
   [libpam-mount](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libpam-mount)
2. configure `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml` with:

   ```
   <debug enable="1" />
   <volume server="server" path="music" mountpoint="~/MyMusicFolder" options="cred=/home/%(USER)/.Music.cred" />
   ```

References:

- the [mount.cifs man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/mount.cifs.8.html)
- the [pam_mount.conf man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man5/pam_mount.conf.5.html)

Comment: Thanks, but step 3 only works for sudo. Therefore, if I script it then it will need to run as root, will it not?

Comment: Also, for step 4 is there any reason I can't just put this in */etc/fstab*?

Comment: Ugh, I think that's because it runs as root so $HOME will refer to root's home. I seem to be in a bind here. If step 3 worked as non-root then I can see how this could work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @KentBoogaart: You're right, you need passwordless sudo for that. I've edited the answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: @KentBoogaart The reason it does not work in `/etc/fstab` is that variables like `$HOME` are not expanded there; variable content substitution is a feature of the shell.

Comment: I just tried both options and neither worked. This is doing my head in! I edited */etc/sudoers* using `visudo`, restarted, then tried running the mount without `sudo` and without a password. I got "only root can do that". Then I tried installing `libpam-mount` and editing its config as suggested. I restarted and . . . nothing. The mount hadn't occurred.

Comment: Oddly, all PAM seems to be doing is removing my mount point directory! I tried turning on debug and checking `dmsg`, but saw nothing from PAM at all.

Comment: @KentBoogaart sorry there were a couple typos in the pam_mount.conf file, can you try again?  Also, you need to explitcitly turn on debugging.  As for the sudo: on my PC, "sudo mount" does not give any error (but I do not have a CIFS share to test here).

Comment: Nope, still no go. I checked dmesg again and noticed something I missed the first time. **[   13.605194] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
[   13.605199] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101** Any idea what would cause this? If I take out my `<volume .../>` from the PAM config then the above does not appear in the log. Also, why on earth would it remove the mountpoint?

Comment: @KentBoogaart seems like a network-related error.  Is your network up before you login? (e.g., wired connection) Or do you need NetworkManager and a password to connect? (e.g., WPA wireless access point)

Comment: It's wireless, and I can confirm that all my googling has led me to believe it's a startup order problem. However, I've not found a solution and I find it difficult to believe that PAM wouldn't already deal with this somehow, but I haven't found any workarounds through its documentation either :S

Comment: Even though I haven't got this working, I'm accepting this as the answer because it *should* work. The only thing (I think) preventing it is another issue in that the wireless network is not started before libpam kicks in. I will start a separate question for that issue.

Comment: I should add that the pam_mount method even allows easy mounting of shares with spaces in the name and target folders also with spaces in the name, which is awesome. No more fiddling around with \040, %20 or \ trying to guess which one is the correct.

Comment: In step 3 if you don't want to add one line per user, you can replace "user" by a wildcard "*". I've tested it, it works. Just mind for the security.

Answer (score 0):

As a note to myself and to others, the reason libpam-mount was failing with:

```
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
```

was due to the fact that my wireless network had not yet started when libpam was attempting the mounts. To rectify this, I had to set the wireless connection as "Available to all users" in the wireless connection settings. This allows the connection to activate prior to a user logging in.

Once I had set that property, libpam-mount worked fine.