# How to auto mount Windows mapped drives per user?

Tags: windows, automount, active-directory

I have a deployment which consists of Windows AD with a share folder for each user.
An example for that : the user john has a share folder \IP/Mapped_Drives/john
SO, what I need is to auto mount these shares to its corresponding users.

I followed this link but with no luck [Auto-mounting network shares per user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67405/auto-mounting-network-shares-per-user)

Because I don't have the credentials, the credentials are in the Active Directory.
SO, Is there a way to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

The only semi-automated way I have found so far is the following:

- Start Nautilus
- File -> Connect to server (save credentials in Gnome-Keyring)
- Set a bookmark for the connection

Now everytime you click on the bookmark, the server drive is mounted. The disadvantage is that every user has to do this once and it will stop working when the AD password changes.